Optimize PySpark code on large dataframe that exceeds cluster resources
I have a large PySpark dataframe containing 250 million rows, with only 2 columns. I am running the minHash code found here. I tried to write the resulting dataframe to parquet files by adj_sdf.write.mode("append").parquet("/output/folder/"). However, I kept getting the error pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers. I can't increase the cluster resources, so I'm wondering if there are ways to optimize the PySpark code instead.
So far, I've done the following:

Partition the dataframe before running the minHash function: sdf = sdf.repartition(200)
Filter out pairs that are unlikely to share many hash values before the final step that involves two joins (hash_sdf.alias('a').join(...)):
filtered_sdf = hash_sdf.filter(f.size(f.col('nodeSet')) > threshold), where threshold = int(0.2 * n_draws)
Set the number of shuffle partitions: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "200")

What else can I do to write the dataframe to parquet files without running into resource problems?

You can try a few things

Use coalesece(num_of_partition) instead of repartition since repartition reduces shuffle operation , you can calculate num_of_partition = Total_data_size// target_size_of_partition.

Persist some data instead of cache
sdf.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

can try to spill data to disk during shuffles.
spark.conf.set("spark.shuffle.spill", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.shuffle.spill.disk", "true")



Based on the code you shared and your response, following might be the reason for the error you are getting:

The /output/folder where you are trying to write the data in a pod is causing the pod to run out of storage. Fixes for this include: writing to a cloud based object storage, or to a directory that has a disk of appropriate size mounted to it.
Assuming it is not because of the output being too large to store for the specified location, it could be due to the persist step. There you can play around with different storage level based on the documentation here here
It might also be prudent to look at the spark dashboard to see if the memory issue is isolated to few executors or all of them or spark driver. If it only few executors then it is likely due to data skew, and you can repartition the data to factor for it.

